# Difference between <input type="button"/> and <button></button>

Tags: html

## Difference between `<input type="button"/>` and `<button></button>` in html5?

```
<input type="button"/> 
<button></button>
```

---

These two tags gives the same output,but why we use it differently?

Answer (score 0):

You can use both. There is no difference in functionality.

> While 'input' elements of type "button" are still perfectly valid
>   HTML, the newer `<button>` element is now the favored way to create
>   buttons. Given that a `<button>`’s label text is inserted between the
>   opening and closing tags, you can include HTML in the label, even
>   images.

Answer (score -2):

`button tag` vs `input type=”button”` attribute

The `<input type=”button”>` and `<button>` tag are two different approach to use Button in HTML document. The difference between them is that the buttons created with the `<button>` tag offer many contributing possibilities than `<input type=”button”>` attribute. The `<button>` can have content inside it. The `<button>` tag permits phrasing content inside button element contents like text or images etc, along work with type functionality defined. But the `input type=”button”` attribute does not permit content. For example, a button tag that contains an image functions and may resemble an input tag whose type is set to “image”, but the button element type allows content. Both examples below very clearly shows the difference.